# Changes made in terminal default back upon reboot

Tags: touchpad, xinput

I currently am using a ThinkPad E14 Gen 4 AMD. On the touchpad, there is by default a middle click if you click in the middle of the touchpad. I always misclick this, meaning to input a left click. To fix this, I entered:

> xinput set-button-map 12 1 1 3 4 5 6 7

which to my understanding, sets the middle click to register as a left click. This fixes my issue, but it seems it resets itself upon device reboot/startup. Is there a command I'm missing to save this change?

Answer (score 1):

This command is active only in the current session. You need to have it [executed automatically when you log in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login).